# Laravel Artisan Version

Tags: php, laravel, command-line-interface, laravel-artisan

On Laravel Artisan CLI, Can I override `php artisan mycommand --version` (--version) and return another string (My own version) ?

```
protected $signature = 'mycommand {--version}';
```

I've tried and it returns Laravel Framework version `Laravel Framework 7.9.2`

Comment: have you tried using only 1 `-`. For example: `mycommand {-version}`?

Comment: @Chemaclass No, I haven't checked that. I would like to give both `--version` and `-v` options. (This is for a package)

Comment: `-v` stands for "verbose" in the CLI console, you shouldn't override that (even if you can)

Comment: You can accept a new flag, like php artisan mycommand --pack-version

Comment: `--version` or `-V` Type `php artisan` and you'll check all currently available commands with their aliases.

Comment: @Tpojka I would like to override `--version` with my own own version number (My own package version number)

Comment: Something is missing here. I don't get it what you want to do exactly. Why don't you make custom command in your package and be able to check it's version with something like `php artisan packagename:version` or like what @mohammad.kaab said?

Comment: @Tpojka Don't you think if we provided `--version` with a package, isn't it  feels more like a native one (Because most are familiar with `--version`, I don't want to introduce another for a simple task like that.) I'm just checking the possibility. If its not possible I will go for a custom one like `mycommand::version`.

Comment: You'll see it's best that way to do so. Changing core files is strongly not recommended.